# Open multiple application in single window

Tags: android, multiprocessing

In one of requirement I need to develop an application where user can launch two application in separate area of screen.

Say Application A in half of the part of screen and in rest of part other application.

I know this could not be straight way to achieve it, but is there any possibility to build such kind of app/launcher. I checked some of mobile ROM support multi application window support.

Any suggestion to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to have this support done on system level, same way Samsung did for example. W/o this you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

this is system level thing unless you make you own customize rom it pretty much impossible to do ,if you want to make customize rom then you will be able to do since its an system level this **launcher uses system property to do so.**